# Создать столбец расстояния до объекта df['disstance'] используя geopy из (df['latitude'], df['longtitude']) и (object_coordinates)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, geopy

Хочу получить столбец с расстояниями до объекта housing['distance'] заполненный значением расстояний.

```
from geopy import distance
object_coord = (56.328351, 44.001842)
housing['lat_long'] = tuple(list(zip(housing.latitude, housing.longtitude)))
housing['distance'] = distance.distance(object_coord, housing['lat_long']).km
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что делаю не так? 
или хотя бы как создать столбец housing['jbject_coord'] заполненный кортежами с одни и тем же значением (56.328351, 44.001842)

Comment: Из приведенного кода непонятно, что за переменная kremlin_coord.

Comment: Исправил, забыл исправить, когда сюда вопрос писал.

Answer (score 3):

Существует гораздо более быстрый (векторизированный) способ посчитать расстояние, используя [haversine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) если вы готовы пожертвовать до 0.5% точности. Потеря точности происходит за счет того что расстояние считается между двумя точками на сфере, а не на сфероиде (как в формуле [Vincenty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vincenty%27s_formulae))

```
# vectorized haversine function
def haversine(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2, to_radians=True, earth_radius=6371):
    """
    Calculate the great circle distance between two points
    on the earth (specified in decimal degrees or in radians)

    All (lat, lon) coordinates must have numeric dtypes and be of equal length.

    """
    if to_radians:
        lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2 = np.radians([lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2])

    a = np.sin((lat2-lat1)/2.0)**2 + \
        np.cos(lat1) * np.cos(lat2) * np.sin((lon2-lon1)/2.0)**2

    return earth_radius * 2 * np.arcsin(np.sqrt(a))
```

Answer (score 0):

Извините, нашел ответ https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/273304/how-to-measure-distance-between-2-gps-points-in-pandas.

housing_handle['distance'] = housing_handle.apply(
    (lambda row: distance(
        (row['latitude'], row['longtitude']),
        (56.328351, 44.001842)
    ).miles),
    axis=1
)