# Есть датасет. Нужно найти ср. длину в км, предварительно выкинув замкнутые траектории у которых совпадают start station id = end station id

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, geopy

Поскольку в данной области новичок, помогите пожалуйста с написанием кода.

[image: Есть такая таблица с данными]

Нужно найти ср. длину в км, предварительно выкинув замкнутые траектории у которых совпадают start station id = end station id. Полагаю что нужно использовать geopy. Но никак не пойму как паре переменных передать корректно значения 'start station latitude', 'start station longitude', 'end station latitude', 'end station longitude'.
Чтобы можно было посчитать расстояние как здесь:

```
New_York = (40.7128, 74.0060) 
Texas = (31.9686, 99.9018) 
geo = geodesic(New_York, Texas).km
```

И как учесть при вычислении расстояния исключение start station id = end station id
Вот мой код:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from geopy.distance import geodesic
    
df = pd.read_csv("/gdrive/My Drive/data/201809-citibike-tripdata.csv")
    
coord1 = ['start station latitude', 'start station longitude']
coord2 = ['end station latitude', 'end station longitude']
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df, columns=coord1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df, columns=coord2)
print(geodesic(coord1, coord2).km)
```

Но на выходе следующее:

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'start station latitude'

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе [mcve] входных данных (__в виде текста / CSV / Python кода или ссылки на файл__) и __то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе__. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь [векторизированной функцией `haversine()`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1050851/211923):

```
def haversine_wrap(df):
    return haversine(
        df["start station latitude"],
        df["start station longitude"],
        df["end station latitude"],
        df["end station longitude"]
    )
```

средняя длина поездки посчитанная по [формуле `haversine`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula):

```
In [15]: haversine_wrap(df.query("`start station id` != `end station id`")).mean()
Out[15]: 1.8495384094636735
```

---

замер скорости работы данного решения:

```
In [52]: df.query("`start station id` != `end station id`").shape
Out[52]: (1836520, 15)

In [53]: %timeit haversine_wrap(df.query("`start station id` != `end station id`")).mean()
324 ms ± 4.11 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

На моем *MacBook Pro* данный код выполняется за 324 миллисекунды для 1.836.520 записей.

Answer (score 0):

Сделал так, но данные большие и вычисляет больше 8 минут.

```
df['point1'] = df.apply(lambda row: Point(latitude=row['start station latitude'], longitude=row['start station longitude']), axis=1)
    df['point2'] = df.apply(lambda row: Point(latitude=row['end station latitude'], longitude=row['end station longitude']), axis=1)
    
    df['distance_km'] = df.apply(lambda row: distance(row['point1'], row['point2']).km if row['point2'] is not row['point1'] else float('nan'), axis=1)
    df = df.drop('point2', axis=1)
    print(df['distance_km'])
    res_mean3 = df['distance_km'].mean()
    print('Средняя длина в км', round(res_mean3,2))
```

Comment: интересно - а чем вам не подошел [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1380548/211923), который работает на порядки быстрее? ;)

Comment: Просто в курсе обучения который я прохожу, в задании было строго сказано использовать geopy

Comment: тогда стоит попробовать использовать `geopandas` - он тоже основан на `geopy`, но с ним удобнее работать )